# I have added rockmongo to my openshift jboss aplication but I cannot import files from the console

Tags: jboss, openshift, rockmongo

I have added rockmongo to my openshift jboss aplication but I cannot import files from the console.

I also have an openshift diy application and have added rockmongo. Here the import works fine from the console.

Why is the problem occuring for the jboss application?

Comment: The file content is unimportant. The problem is that rockmongo is saying that importing is unauthorized no matter what I put in the file.

Comment: I removed the rockmongo cartridge from my jboss application and then re-added it....and magically it now allows import as required.

Answer (score -1):

I removed the rockmongo cartridge from my jboss application and then re-added it....and magically it now allows import as required.